# Crawler/parser for Xapian

Tags: solr, web-crawler, xapian

I would like to implement a search engine which should crawl a set of web sites, extract specific information from the pages and create full-text index of that specific information.

It seems to me that Xapian could be a good choice for the search engine library.

What are the options for a crawler/parser to integrate with Xapian?

Would Solr be a better choice than Xapian to integrate with open source crawlers/parsers?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/solr-adoption-power-of-sane-defaults/#comment-32560) a little comparison between Xapian and Solr.

But if you want to build a crawler, take a look at [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/). It's [extensible with plugins](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/PluginCentral), so you could write a plugin that analyzes the information that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Flax](http://www.flax.co.uk/) may provide some of what you're looking for.